# How to get values for primary light intensity etc, from ARDirectionalLightEstimate

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

So I'm trying to use the front camera of iPhone XR to get the approximate location for light sources. I decided to use `ARDirectionalLightEstimate` but I can't figure out how to access it. I can easily access `lightEstimate` property.

The Docs said that the `lightEstimate` property of each frame has an instance of `ARDirectionalLightEstimate` but I can't access it using the dot operator, I even tried to type cast it to `ARDirectionalLightEstimate` (like I saw someone doing, I can't find the link right now but I will update) but that didn't work too. I am inexperienced in swift so it's possible I messed up somewhere.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`ARDirectionalLightEstimate` is a subclass of type `ARLightEstimate`, so to access you need to type cast `lightEstimate`:

```
let lightEstimate = sceneView?.session.currentFrame?.lightEstimate
if let directionalLightEstimate = lightEstimate as? ARDirectionalLightEstimate {
    // add logic here
    let primaryLightIntensity = directionalLightEstimate.primaryLightIntensity
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks, I will try this out as soon as I get the time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/ardirectionallightestimate) for `ARDirectionalLightEstimate`, this will only work if a configuration of type `ARFaceTrackingConfiguration` is running, and doesn't seem to work for any other (it also won't work when running a `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration` with `userFaceTrackingEnabled` enabled).